# Acessing multiple structure fields in matlab without looping through it

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

I Have a 8x18 structure with each cel containing a column vector of occurrences of a single event. I want to obtain data from some of these fields concatenated in a single array, without having to loop through it. I can't seem to find a way to vertically concatenate the fields I am interested in in a single array.

As an example I create the following structure with between 1 and 5 occurrences per cell:

```
s(62).vector(8,18).heading.occurrences=[1;2;3];
for i=1:62
    for j=1:8
        for k=1:18
            y=ceil(rand(1)*5);
            s(i).vector(j,k).heading.occurrences=rand(y,1);
        end
    end
end
```

Now if want to obtain all occurrences in several cells while keeping `i` constant at for instant `i=1` the following works:

```
ss=s(1).vector([1 26 45]);                     
h=[ss.heading];            
cell2mat({h.occurrences}')
```

Now I would want to do the same for `s`, for instance `s([1 2 3]).vector([1 26 45])`, how would that work? I have tried `xx=s([1 2 3])`, `yy=xx.vector([1 26 45])` but this however yields the error:

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 3 results.

Is this also possible with a vector operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution that accommodates using index vectors for `s` and the field `vector`:

```
sIndex = [1 2 3];    % Indices for s
vIndex = [1 26 45];  % Indices for 'vector' field

v = reshape(cat(3, s(sIndex).vector), 144, []);
h = [v(vIndex, :).heading];
out = vertcat(h.occurrences);
```

It uses [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to concatenate all the `vector` fields into an 8-by-18-by-`numel(sIndex)` matrix, [reshapes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that into a 144-by-`numel(sIndex)` matrix, then indexes the rows specified by `vIndex` and collects their `heading` and `occurrences` fields, using [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) instead of [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to vectorize the entire operation, but this should work.

```
% get vector field and store in cell array
s_new = { s(1:3).vector };

% now extract heading field, this is a cell-of-cells
s_new_heading = cellfun(@(x) { x.heading }', s_new, 'UniformOutput', false);

occurences = {};
for iCell = 1:length(s_new_heading)
    % use current cell
    cellHere = s_new_heading{iCell};

    % retain indices of interest, these could be different for each cell
    cellHere = cellHere([ 1 26 45 ]);

    % extract occurrences
    h = cellfun(@(x) x.occurrences, cellHere, 'UniformOutput', false);
    h_mat = cell2mat(h);

    % save them in cell array 
    occurences = cat(1, occurences, h_mat);
end
```